# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens dotrine and doctrine

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

there is a function used to decrease the number of sellers of a book in our project it is that function

```
class listab_Model_Books extends listab_Model_BaseBooks
{
    public function decreaseSeller($code)
    {
        $row = Doctrine_Query::create()
               ->from('listab_Model_Books b')
               ->where('b.code = ?',$code)
               ->fetchOne();
//            var_dump($row['seller']);
       $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
               ->from('listab_Model_Books b')
               ->set('b.seller = ?',$row['seller']-1)
               ->where('b.code = ?',$code)
               ->execute();
    }
}
```

when i try to use this function it gives me this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens dotrine
```

what am i doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited** for correctness.

I believe "set" should be used only with update, like this:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
->update('listab_Model_Books b')
->set('b.seller', '?', $row['seller']-1)
->where('b.code = ?',$code)
->execute();
```

If what you are trying is to do an update you should use the "update" clause. Otherwise it'll be taken as a select.